# Как выявить процесс, который осуществляет syn-flood

Tags: linux, tcp-ip, kali-linux, tcpdump

Есть процесс, который осуществляет syn-flood, например hping3 в Kali. Каким образом его выявить?
Пробовал разные вариации ключей netstat, ss, watch, например:

1. netstat -n -p | grep SYN_SENT
2. watch -n 1 "ss -t4 state syn-sent"
3. while true; do netstat -ntup | grep $IP ; done

Но никакого эффекта нет, как будто никакого флуда не осуществляется.
Команда:

tcpdump -nnni any port 22

отображает процесс флуда, но к сожалению, не способна отобразить PID.
Подскажите рабочий способ пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поищи в `raw`-сокетах

```
sudo ss -ap | grep raw
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!